# How to drag file using keyboard in VLC player in windows?

Tags: windows

Is there is anyway I can drag media file to VLC software by keyboard instead of using mouse ?

Comment: Are you sure you need mouse drag? If you want to open a file from windows explorer, you can select it using the arrow keys and press the enter key. If VLC is not your standard application for the file type, you can press the context menu key (typically left of the right ctrl key) and navigate to "open with... -> VLC" using the arrow keys.

Answer (score 1):

The [MouseKeys](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/14204/windows-7-use-mouse-keys-to-move-mouse-pointer) accessibility feature should work for this. You can turn it on via the Ease of Access Center in the Control Panel. Or with left-Alt + left-Shift + Num Lock. This will allow you to control the mouse with the numeric keypad. For example: 2, 4, 6, and 8 move the pointer, and 1, 3, 7, and 9 move it diagonally.

To start the drag, point to the item and press zero. Drag it with the number keys. Press the decimal point to drop it.

Comment: Is there is any other way as this is not efficient enough the pointer is moving on slow phase by keyboard as compare to mouse

Comment: I agree that it is very, very slow. But it's the only way I have found to drag and drop files with the keyboard. Sorry.